# Frames Skipping while working with Android Animation

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview, imageview

I have two fragments on the same screen. One is changing image after every 3 seconds and the other is showing a text with a horizontal animation (from left to right). The image fragment is setting the image from external memory using the method setImageURI.

The problem occurs when a new image is loaded in the view, animated text on the other fragment skips its frames and a kind of glitch appears on that fragment interface.

I have tried changing the image on a Runnable thread as well but that didnt work as well.

Can anyone suggest something better?

And also....can the problem be resolved using a device with a better RAM?